# Google sheet OAuth fails to identify user

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-oauth

I wrote a google sheet script to read data in a spreadsheet and based on the user's email `Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()`, places corresponding events in the user's calendar. On my own google login this works as expected after I authorize the script (non verified and non secure). I assume this is because I'm the developer of the code. When my colleagues try to do the same thing (the worksheet is shared with them) the code can't determine the user's email when the code is run, but when using debug the correct email is retrieved and the code continues to execute fine.

I'm trying to authorize the webapp with OAuth, but can't figure out what steps I have to follow to make API calls from inside google sheet. An authorized domain is asked, I have no idea what I have to give here.

Flow of the code requesting authorization (I guess): `Calendar.CalendarList.list();` (all calendars from my colleagues are listed) --> user selects calendar --> `Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()` (code returns 'undefined', in debug mode a correct adres is retrieved) --> based on the email specific data is retrieved from the worksheet --> `Calendar.Events.insert(event, calendarId);`

**Summary:** What is the correct procedure to authorize my script to retrieve the ActiveUser's email to be used in a google sheet script shared with a limited number of users? We don't use GSuite.

Comment: Have you reviewed the permissions model for user identity? Because you are not in a Gsuite domain that method will fail. Probably you must request access in the script OAuth scopes to the user identity and then use that associated Google API (and not the `Session` instance).

Comment: Try manually adding `profile` to oauthScopes manifest.

Comment: The auto-generated scope items are missing when manually adding some items in the oauthScopes manifest. I can't seem to find all the correct reference for them (https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes). The code isn't functional without all relevant ones declared.